# Why am I getting an additional "*" on some lines of my python app?

Tags: python

I've been asked for my A Level computing to create a text based hangman game. For some reason, when the "guessword" is displayed, it contains an additional character at the end, which cannot be solved, and therefore makes the game unwinnable. This only happens on a few circumstances, not every word in the list has this additional character.

Here is the python code:

```
import random

class Hangman():

def Playing(self):

    category = raw_input("Please select a category from; EuroCapitals; PremTeams; FruitAndVeg")
    again = True
    while again:

        guessword = open(category + ".txt", "r").readlines()[random.randint(0,9)]
        board = "*" * (len(guessword) - 1)
        alreadySaid = set()
        mistakes = 7

        print(" ".join(board))

        guessed = False
        while not guessed and mistakes > 0:

            whatplayersaid = raw_input("Guess a letter: ")

            if whatplayersaid in guessword:
                alreadySaid.add(whatplayersaid)
                board = "".join([char if char in alreadySaid else "*" for char in guessword])
                if board == guessword:
                    guessed = True
            else:
                mistakes -= 1
                print("Nope.", mistakes, "mistakes left.")

            print(" ".join(board))

        again = (input("Again [y/n]: ").lower() == 'y')


Hangman().Playing()
```

And the list of words in "EuroCapitals.txt" is as follows:

```
london
paris
madrid
berlin
moscow
rome
amsterdam
bern
zagreb
stockholm
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a `\n` character (or maybe some extra whitespace?) from the file -- `readlines()` will preserve them if they are in the file. So, you want to `.rstrip()` your `guessword`, e.g.:

```
    guessword = open(category + ".txt", "r").readlines()[random.randint(0,9)].rstrip()
```

As an aside, creating an anonymous file object like this generally isn't a good idea, because it won't be closed right away. You're better off using a `with` statement:

```
    with open(category + ".txt", "r") as f:
        guessword = f.readlines()[random.randint(0,9)].rstrip()
```

and you could further refine it with

```
    with open(category + ".txt", "r") as f:
        guessword = random.choice(f.readlines()).rstrip()
```